# Upload Android app to google play step by step...?

Tags: android, certificate, apk, google-play, distribute

1)
I'm newbie to android distribution,my application is ready and now I want to distribute it through google play. But I can't find how to create certificate, because default debug certificate not use for distribute.
can any one help me to create self signed certificate.
I'm using mac os and eclipse as ide for development.

2)
After creating appropriate .apk with self signed certificate. what is the process to upload it and where? Is there any account I've to create on google play through which I can upload and manage my app (like iphone developer account).

Comment: It's all explained in the documentation. Ask again if you have specific problems with any of the steps. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Read through these documents: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html

Comment: Hello, Graham Borland, thanks for reply...yes I go through all this documents, but like there is------ You can use standard tools — Keytool and Jarsigner — to generate keys and sign your application .apk files.
After you sign your application for release, we recommend that you use the zipalign tool to optimize the final APK package.------so how i can use this tool in my mac that I want to know, there is no help regarding to that...!?!

Comment: Its a shame the answer is on 8 upvotes but the OP gets murdered...

Comment: @Neil: Apparently Google's description on uploading isn't as straight forward as people think.  I was surprised by this as well.

Comment: I am frustrated that questions such as these are downvoted... the documentation that "explains all" is horrible, which is why @Deer asked the question in the first place!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[Can't get a better breakdown than the source.](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/index.html)

Easy Mode:

1. Since you're using eclipse, just click "File->Export->Export Android Application".  Follow the wizard's instructions.  You'll need to create a keystore with password.  Within the keystore, you'll need to create a key to sign the app with.  The key can have the same password as the keystore or a different one.  KEEP THE KEYSTORE AND PASSWORDS.  You will need to use the SAME EXACT KEY every time you want to update your app.  Failing to do so will require you to resubmit your app as a different program on the store.
2. Go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish/.  Create your account.  You'll have to pay a one-time fee of $25 to submit.  Once there, you'll have access to your console. Click the button "Upload Application", follow the instructions, input the info, click "Save".  If everything is the way you like it, click "Publish".  Grab some coffee, read a book, play a game, go to the gym, whatever.  Come back a couple hours later and you and everyone else will be able to download the app from the store.

This is all assuming you have ONE apk that is LESS THAN 50MB in size.  Things get more complicated when you have to implement [expansion files](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html), [multiple APKs](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html), [app licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/index.html), or any of the other [Google Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/index.html).

**UPDATE**

As of September 2015, the maximum size of an APK on the Google Play store can be 100MB before you have to use expansion files.

Comment: If you don't KEEP THE KEYSTORE PASSWORD, but remember your alias password, you CAN bust it open with the following resource https://plus.google.com/+ZachKlippenstein/posts/6jshPnmn2PW --> https://gist.github.com/zach-klippenstein/4631307/download