# Error with manifest when uploading APK to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, basic4android

When I upload my APK to Google Play, I get this error about my manifest:
[image: Google Play error]

I used Basic4Android to make my application.

This is my manifest file: 
[image: Manifest image]

Please help.

Comment: what do you mean with zip file?

Comment: By the way you should target the latest sdk version: 19 instead of 14.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading a zip file that contains the Manifest and the apk file, then please don't. You just have to upload/submit the apk file. Make sure that you sign the apk file with a release key and not the default debug key/certificate.

Your apk file already contains manifest file in it. So, no need to zip it again.

More info on prepping your apk for release: [Prep for publish](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html#publishing-prepare)
HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You do not upload a `.zip` file you just upload the `.apk`. Google play can get the `AndroidManifest.xml` data straigt from the `.apk` file.

For more just follow the [Publishing Guide](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/index.html)

---

You can also check out that answer:

[Upload Android app to google play step by step...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759610/upload-android-app-to-google-play-step-by-step)

---

Signing Guides for [Basic4Android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/signing-your-application-before-uploading-to-google-play.6756/), [Android Developer Console](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: I search and find my problem. I not used zipalign tool.
Image: http://i.imgur.com/5qeORMJ.png

Comment: Yes signed. I use Basic4Android.

Comment: http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/signing-your-application-before-uploading-to-google-play.6756/

Comment: I already signed my app but same error. I which password write to sign window? I wrote random password.

Comment: have you read and folow all the steps at the url and still have problem?